# Grab the number data from website after "::before" tag using Jsoup/Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, jsoup

How to get information inside  tag ?

Below HTML code show example of the content. I alredy tried to use Selenium and Jsoup to get the information:

[image]

I already used this sample code with:

1. Jsoup:

   ```
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
   Elements textField = doc.select("div.GgQLrpF");
   Elements likes = textField.select("strong._2s0Qnur");

   return likes.text();
   ```
2. Using Xpath Selenium:

   ```
   WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/article/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/strong"));
   ```

Both solution doesn't work well, and I can't get the number data at this moment.

Comment: can you provide the link to website? @deisy

Comment: That xpath though, OMG!!

Comment: Don't think JSoup offers any way to access pseudo-element content (most DOM models don't, it requires applying the CSS). Don't know about Selenium.

Comment: Can you provide us with more information? Are the class names stable or generated dynamically and change each time you request the page from the webserver? What makes your code fail? Look here about how you can improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi, give us an example page to test it out, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really sorry, but I wasn't able to write back faster.

I found solution. I had to use cssselector as T.J.Crowder said in answer:

This sample code show the result properly:

```
public String getEmotiveDataLike() {
    WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div._1H1-_iz"));
    WebElement finalWebElement = webElement.findElement(By.cssSelector("strong._2s0Qnur"));
    return finalWebElement.getText();
}
```

Thanks you for all the interest!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//strong[@class='_2s0Qnur']"));
return element.gettext();
```

Comment: I will check out if your answer is also properly, and feedback tomorrow